# Offline installer for Visual Studio 2017 cumulative updates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Does anyone know how I can get offline installers for Visual Studio 2017 cumulative updates? In this instance, I'm after cumulative update 26628.09:  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-au/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#mar14

Comment: I just installed this update and I am now unable to open any solution; VS crashes immediately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the instructions under How to update an offline installer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio) is what you are after:

- To refresh your offline installation folder so that it includes the latest updates, run the --layout command again. Make sure to point to the same folder that you used before; this way, **only those components that have been updated since you last ran --layout will be downloaded**.

then

- To update a Visual Studio instance that you installed from an offline installation folder, run the Visual Studio Installer, and then click Update.

I haven't tried it though to check if the cumulative update gets downloaded by running with --layout again.

Comment: Thiago offline installer for update 2 (26430.04) does not work. Failed installation screwed up my development environment.

Comment: Did they move/remove the "update" button that this answer says to click on? After updating the install point and launching the Visual Studio Installer, there is no "update" to click on.